# R Structural Equation Model in R with random effect error

Tags: r, data-science, lme4, nlme

Constructing a nonlinear structural equation model with random error term in R

```
library(piecewiseSEM)
library(lme4)
library(nlme)

head(VTmodelmeansadults)
            id Round Cycle Day Stage Temp Type   Sample Pos   md possal posabd  mat.max mat.mean adj.r8    cage matage
70 1 G1 3 27 1      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27 1 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
73 1 G1 3 27.2      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27.2 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
76 1 G1 3 27.3      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27.3 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
82 1 G1 3 27.4      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27.4 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
85 1 G1 3 27.5      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27.5 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
88 1 G1 3 27.7      1    G1   3  G1 3   27  abd 27.7 abd   0 0.25      0      0 2.426511   0.6378      0 G1 3 27      3
```

As you can see from the data, I want to know the effect of day, md, and cycle on the binomial outcome Pos. md is itself influenced by Temp and matage, and there is a random effect of cage.

```
 model = list(
   lme(md ~ Temp + matage, random = ~ 1|cage, na.action = na.omit,
       data = VTmodelmeansadults),

   glmer(Pos ~ Day + md + Cycle +(1|cage), 
         family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = VTmodelmeansadults))

summary(model)
     Length Class    Mode
[1,] 18     lme      list
[2,]  1     glmerMod S4
```

When evaluating model fit I get the following error message

```
sem.fit(model, VTmodelmeansadults)
  |========================================|  75%
Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1
```

I've tried substituting lmer() for lme() in case there was an aliasing issue but get this error

```
model = list(
   lmer(md ~ Temp + matage + (1|cage), na.action = na.omit,
      data = VTmodelmeansadults),

  glmer(Pos ~ Day + md + Cycle +(1|cage), 
         family=binomial(link = "logit"), data = VTmodelmeansadults))

sem.fit(model, VTmodelmeansadults)
  |==================================================================|  75%
Error in KRmodcomp.lmerMod(basis.mod.new, basis.mod.drop) : 
  Models have either equal fixed mean stucture or are not nested'
```

Could it still be an aliasing issue? Or maybe the glmer model conflicts with the lmer model?

Any help is much appreciated.

Methods adapted from jshlefe's super helpful piecewiseSEM package
https://github.com/jslefche/piecewiseSEM

Comment: You have included `na.action=omit` in one of your models but not the other. Is there any chance that you are ending up with different analyzed samples as a result?

Comment: @jslefche thinks this is a problem with pbkrtest and not piecewiseSEM - any further thoughts, Jon? https://github.com/jslefche/piecewiseSEM/issues/152